# sum 2 row value in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I am trying to sum 2 values in the same column but in 2 different rows

this is my code

```
public function index()
{
    
    $orders = Order_Ecommerces::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
    
    foreach ($orders as $key) {
        $totalpricePerOrder=DB::table('order_ecommerce_product')->where('order_ecommerce_id', '=', $key['id'])->get();

            foreach ($totalpricePerOrder as $key) {
        
                $selectProduct=DB::table('products')->where('id','=',$key->product_id)->sum('prezzo_al_pezzo');
        
            }
    }
    
    
    return view('ecommerce.orders', compact('orders','selectProduct'));
}
```

the result of first foreach is an collection

[collection foreach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afkvq.png)

it does not give me the sum of the 2 lines but only the valueof the last row

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: please try to use 
 ```DB::table('products')->select(DB:raw(sum('prezzo_al_pezzo')))->where('id','=',$key->product_id); ```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```php
DB::table('order_ecommerce_product')->sum('prezzo_al_pezzo');
```

or if you need a filters in your query:

```php
DB::table('order_ecommerce_product')
    ->whereIn('order_ecommerce_id', $orderIds)
    ->sum('prezzo_al_pezzo');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#aggregates